# The relation of a person you share a half-sibling with

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, kinship-terms

My parents, Bianca and Ivan, are currently married and have always been since I was born.

Bianca had a previous relationship with Henry with whom she had a son named John, thus John and I are half-brothers. John has two other half-brothers named David and Santiago, they all share the same father but I do not have any parents in common them.

Ivan (my birth-father) had a previous relationship with Alicia and they have two sons named Frank and Ernst, so Frank and Ernst are my half-brothers. Ivan also had a relationship with Katy and they have a daughter named Pamela, so Pamela and I are half-siblings. Pamela also has a half-sister named Merari because they have the same birth-mother.

Merari, Santiago, and David and I are not blood-related, but they share the same half-siblings with me.

Is there a name for this relationship? I’m just curious.

Comment: It's called the new world family! (Technically accurate description: David is my half-sibling's half-sibling but not my full- or half-sibling.) If there isn't a word for it now then there will be in future.

Comment: Try Googling "Inheritance Law".  People with the remotest claims to fortune have been trying their luck for centuries.  Lawyers and courts have this nailed.

Comment: There are too many "Ivans" in this anecdote. Could you just narrow it down to **one** instance of the relationship you seek, please? Use pseudonyms if necessary so that there is only one of any name.  I suspect the answer is "You're not related," but currently it's just too complicated to be sure.

Comment: To avoid confusion, as pointed out by @Andrew Leach, this question could be simplified as follows: "John is my half-brother having the same mother. John has another half-brother David having the same father, entirely unrelated to me. So David and I are unrelated by blood or marriage but we have the same half-sibling (John) -- is there a word for how David and I are related?"

Comment: "friends-in-law, once removed"

Comment: I drew it out. There's actually just one Ivan. This Ivan had a child (Samuel) by Bianca, and had two children (Frank and Ernst) by Alicia, and had a child (Pamela) by Katty. Katty also had a child (Merari) by some unnamed XY. On Bianca's side, other than Samuel by Ivan, she had a child (John) by Henry. And Henry had two children (David and Santiago) by some unnamed XX. That said, I agree with @EnglishStudent that the question could be greatly simplified.

Comment: I know of a case like this, and the three adult children merely call themselves "brothers", even though two of them have no parents in common.

Comment: "Brothers" is appropriate enough here for general purposes in the family context @ Samuel, as kindly noted by @shoover.

Comment: English does not have terms for complicated family relationships or connections.  So there is no name for the relationship you describe, (which is more of a non-relationship than a relationship).  To make one up, you are half brothers at one remove.

Comment: @ab2 is very right to note that *"English does not have terms for complicated family relationships or connections.*" __ it is a fact of the language @ Samuel, as so many native users have observed in response to [such questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinship-terms). But English also offers much scope for invention, although it becomes a 'proper word' only if enough people begin to use it: so I was thinking, since half of half is a quarter: can you call your half-sibling's half-sibling your *quarter-sibling?*

Comment: @English Student is right that you can make up a term for the relationship you describe.  My suggestion is virtual half brothers at one horizontal remove.  See [cousins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin) for the "remove"  part.  Horizontal because they are of the same generation.   Virtual because they are not real brothers.   I don't recommend this because you will spend too much time explaining it.  Just say "sort of half brothers".

Comment: @EnglishStudent I don't think *quarter-sibling* works for a half-sibling of a half-sibling because (1) you'd be your own quarter-sibling; but more to the point, (2) the DNA half that (say) Merari shares with Pamela is the half that Pamela *doesn't* share with the OP.

Comment: Yes indeed an inaccurate term @Lawrence: a biologist friend recently told me that "quarter" sibling implies at least 25% DNA in common, but the 2 persons are unrelated here. Does this type of family relation have a single word or phrase in *any* language?

Comment: @Andrew Leach so we don’t count as stepsiblings?

Comment: @ab2 so we don’t count as stepsiblings?

Comment: @Samuel No, I don't think so: a stepsibling is the child of a stepparent, brought into your family when your own parent remarried. However, the question is so complicated with so many people involved that it's really impossible to say. ***Please*** simplify the question to ***just one*** relationship. Or draw a diagram.

Answer (score 1):

### Stepbrother/Stepsister

Paraphrasing Dictionary.com:

> The son (/daughter) of one's stepparent who is not the son (/daughter) of either of one's biological parents. The stepson (/daughter) of one's parent who is not one's half-brother (/sister).

This is used when parents with existing children remarry, even if no "bridge" half-sibling comes along later; and there's no point in making up another term.

Comment: Hm...looks like this has been a draft since OP first posted the question.

Comment: So do they count as stepsiblings or no?

Comment: @Samuel Yes, but the gendered terms are more commonly used.